# How to Build a Nodejitsu style PaaS

Tags: node.js, paas, nodejitsu

I'm relatively new to Node.js and the PaaS scene and I'm interested in building a somewhat similar service. Can someone enlighten me on how Nodejitsu's (or similar providers') components (ie http-proxy, spawning node processes, load balancing, hardware infrastructures) fit together?

Thank you!

Comment: ["If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well fortunately there is a company that ran a Node.js PaaS that open sourced all of their code. They were purchased by AppFog.

1. [Nodester.com](http://nodester.com/)
2. [Nodester source](https://github.com/nodester)

I'd imagine that reviewing this code would answer your question.